# gunicorn serving django app produces no log on exceptions

Tags: web-server, deployment, django

I am trying to serve a Django app using gunicorn. In my current setup running on Debian 6 (production) and Ubuntu 11.04 (development), gunicorn (v0.12) is behind nginx and managed by supervisor. The setup runs OK, except that exceptions are not logged.

It is the same if I run gunicorn from the command line: `manage.py run_gunicorn 127.0.0.1:XXXX`. Again there's no output. The problem applies only to ERROR-level events, INFO-level output is produced when workers get started. The traceback is displayed on the page if `DEBUG = True`.

The app runs on Django v1.3 with no changes in the default logging settings.

Today v0.13 featuring a refactor of logging has become available, but the issue is still there.

I'd very much appreciate any help.

Edit: I got error emailing working, it is irrelevant to the logging issue.

Comment: Handle the logging with a logger in the application code, instead of expecting the server to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you get no log message upon an error 500? After about 30 seconds into a request? In that case, gunicorn killed off its child process that was serving you. And it kills in a quick and hard way that leaves no logging.